# Create grid pattern using span / images keep same height

Tags: css

trying to create a grid pattern that can be replicated as much as needed looking like picture below.
My 4*5 images only fill up 4 rows and leave last one empty, why ?

[image]

```
  .grid-image {
  width: 24em;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid img:nth-child(1n),
.grid img:nth-child(4n) {
  grid-row: span 5;
}
.grid img:nth-child(2n),
.grid img:nth-child(3n) {
  grid-row: span 4;
}

    <div class="grid">
    {% for image in images %}
        <img src="/assets/Images/tattoo/{{ image }}" alt="{{ image }}" class="grid-image">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: do the images have the correct size? I miss any declarations that ensure the correct 4x5 or 4x4 aspect ratio.

Comment: @tacoshy isn't "  height: auto;" in "  .grid-image {
  width: 24em;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
"
doing what you mean  ?

Comment: not necessarily as the height of the rows is not fixed. It is calculated to fit the content and also could take a height of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 issues:

- you use `object-fit: contain` which will not fit the grid space but contains the image as a whole without stretching. If the image does not have exactly either a 4x5 or respectively a 4x4 ratio, the image will leave white space.
- You never declared an aspect ratio and as such the row height is auto and calculated to fit the element. As such it can also have a height of 0. You need to declare the aspect ratio.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container img:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  aspect-ratio: 4/5;
  grid-row: span 5;
}

.container img:nth-child(2n + 2) {
  aspect-ratio: 4/4;
  grid-row: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90.jpg">
</div>
```

If you using a pre-compiler such as SASS or LESS you could also nest the CSS as such:

```scss
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    &:nth-child(2n + 1) {
      aspect-ratio: 4/5;
      grid-row: span 5;
    }
    &:nth-child(2n + 2) {
      aspect-ratio: 4/4;
      grid-row: span 4;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Any particular reason you chose display:block ?

Comment: @PhilibertEtienne images by default are inline elements (treated the same as `inline-block` by most browsers).  Inline elements (including images)  have by default a descender space below to reserve space below the baseline for letters such as q, p, g, j, y. Using `display: block` removes the descender space and the "unwanted" white space it causes.

Comment: I made a snippet that show what I described: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/vYQqmWr